# Adjust white fill between paragraphs in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Latex seems to fill in white space between the paragraphs by default, to get every page to end at approx the same height (at least with the book and scrreprt class). This is all fine, but I have a couple of pages with only two paragraphs. Latex insists on putting in 2cm of white space between them, which looks bad. I know that I can use \raggedrift for the whole document, but I kind of like the white fill except for the pages with only two paragraphs. I have also tried to adjust manually with \vspace{-1cm}, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to set a maximum value to the height of white fill between paragraphs?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your mostly-empty pages are because the following content starts on a new page (at the end of a chapter, for example), then the easiest way to fix it is probably to insert a vertical fill after your last paragraph.  The vertical fill should expand to occupy the extra space, keeping the inter-paragraph fill small.

You can change the vertical space applied to *every* paragraph by setting the value of `\parskip`.

Comment: Didn't work but: I inserted a new paragraph in white color. Maybe not the most sophisticated solution, but it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. At the end of the last paragraph of the page, add '\vfill'. This will fill up the rest of the page, making the two paragraphs on it move as close to each other as they would normally.
I just tested it myself and it works.